# Passing vector in class without copying

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a class:

someclass header code:

```
class SomeClass{
    SomeClass();
    vector<int> somePointerVector;

    public:
    SomeClass(vector<int> &someVector);
};
```

Im a little confused about how to use vectors here.  I'd like to set somePointerVector = someVector, so that I can manipulate the data in someVector with other parts of the class using somePointerVector and I also don't want to copy all of someVectors data.

With an array I'd do it with:

```
int* somePointerArray = someArray;
```

But how would I do this with vectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `somePointerVector` a reference and put it in the [initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) of your class. (And please give it a better name.)

```
class SomeClass
{
    vector<int> &somePointerVector;

  public:
    SomeClass(vector<int> &someVector)
      : somePointerVector(someVector)
    {}
};
```

Comment: Cool, didn't really know initialization lists existed.  Jw, what is the proper way to format an initialization list with multiple initializations?

Comment: Well, you put commas in between the items; that's all the compiler cares about. I would put the various members on separate lines and align them with the first one (not with the `:`), but there are various styles of formatting them.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the most-appropriate solution, you need to understand the lifetime and ownership of 'SomeClass' and the vector that it's passed. For example, if SomeClass takes the vector by reference, then the code that constructs SomeClass needs to make sure that the lifetime of the vector is greater than that of SomeClass - otherwise SomeClass could end-up with a reference that is no longer valid. By passing by reference, SomeClass isn't 'taking ownership' of the vector

Alternatively, if the code that constructs SomeClass wants to 'hand-off' responsiblity of the vector (and you have a compiler and STL implementation that is 'r-value reference aware'), then you can pass an r-value reference to the vector;

```
class SomeClass { 
    vector<int> data_;

 public:
    SomeClass(vector<int>&& data) : data_(data) 
}
```

The code that constructs SomeClass would then;

```
vector<int> data;
data.push_back(1);
data.push_back(2);
data.push_back(3);
data.push_back(4);

SomeClass someClass(std::move(data));
```

In this case, you've 'moved' the vector into SomeClass to avoid copying, and SomeClass has 'taken ownership' of the 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
class SomeClass {
    vector<int> myVector;

    void MyMethod(vector<int>* theVector);
}
```

and in your method

```
void SomeClass::MyMethod(vector<int>* theVector)
{
    theVector->push_back(7);
}
```

Been ages since I worked with STL, but I think it's push_back?

Oh, and to use indices you could just (*theVector)[2]...